# Gradle multiple android apps

Tags: android, gradle, apk, android-productflavors

I want with help of gradle build 2-3 different APKs where the app name changes and some lines of code. I don't want to change whole directories or whole files, only snippets of code, is this possible? 
I have tried to understand [Build variants and Product flavor](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants). but can't figure out how it works. Also this [tutorial](http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a suggestion. We faced the same thing and this is how we got it to work. In my opinion it's very clean and yes it does use product flavors.

So let's say you have a class Address, which is formatted differently from country to country, but of course has a lot of common code. For the sake of simplicity let's say you have only `street_number` and `street_name`, but on country `A` the address should be formatted as `street_number street_name` and on country `B` it should be formatted as `street_name, street_number`.

The way we did this was having a project structure like so:

`src
   |
   |\ main
   |\ countryA
   |\ countryB`

So the project has 2 flavors - `countryA` and `countryB`. Here's the relevant `build.gradle` part:

```
productFlavors {
    countryA {
        applicationId "com.countryA"
    }
    countryB {
        applicationId "com.countryB"
    }
}
```

Now for the code part. So `Address` is a common class which we placed inside `main` and would look more or less like:

```
public abstract class AbstractAddress {
  private String streetNumber;
  private String streetName;

  // ... your favorite getters and setters plus some common methods

  public abstract String getFormattedAddress();
}
```

The key here is that the class is abstract and the sub-classes need to implement `getFormattedAddress()`. Now in the `countryA` folder you'd have:

```
package com.myapp.addresses;

public class Address extends AbstractAddress {
  public String getFormattedAddress() {
     return getStreetNumber() + " " + getStreetName();
  }
}
```

Now in the same package as in `countryA` but in `countryB`'s folder, you'd have the same class, but with a different implementation:

```
package com.myapp.addresses;

public class Address extends AbstractAddress {
  public String getFormattedAddress() {
     return getStreetName() + ", " + getStreetNumber();
  }
}
```

Gradle will take care of generating the tasks for you. Something on the lines of `assembleCountryA` and `assembleCountryB` (It also depends on the build variants you have). Of course you can also generate all apks using only one task.

Comment: So if i understand this right, gradle will automatically build one APK with main + the files in countryA and one APk with main + files in countryB ?

Comment: @DanielStorch correct. Gradle will take care of that for you.

Comment: Thanks, would this also mean i get 2 different APK with different names?

Comment: you get 2 apks with different names. Gradle adds the flavor name to them. It's possible to rename them further, but I didn't realize you wanted this. I thought you just wanted 2 different apks, which gradle does it for you.